# Windows Mail error 0x80070003

Tags: windows, email, imap

I am currently having trouble configuring the Windows mail application, when I click on the option to add a Google account it gives me the error code `0x80070003`. I found an alternative however with constraints: IMAP, I have to enter my Gmail address but instead of entering my standard password I have to create an application password. This really annoys me so how can I fix this problem?

Options available (mail app):

[image: Options available (mail app)]

Google selected:

[image: Google selected]

Comment: Try repairing Mail.  Start, Settings, Apps,  and then look from Mail.  Repair and Reset.  I do not use Mail (I use Outlook), but after repairing, Mail sets up OK.

Comment: Which Windows version? Are you using the latest version and is it fully updated?

Comment: I did this on Windows 11 and it works. Same procedure should work on Windows 10

Comment: Im actually on windows 11 22H2 Latest insider beta channel 22623.891 and repair + reset doesnt work btw even in the windows settings (which is linked to windows mail) i cant connect to google services.

Comment: You should only have to create the "application password" once. Are you saying that it asks you to do that more than once?

Comment: Im actually on windows 11 22H2 Latest insider beta channel 22623.891 and repair + reset doesnt work    ..... It works for me in Insider 22H2 +  and in Production 22H2.   Maybe something else has gone wrong.

Comment: @AndrewMorton just once but application password is known for being secureless (free access for all my google account). John i agree with you something might goes wrong so what advise you to solve my issue, i already try basic sfc /scannow or DSIM commands